# Integrate Stripe with Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, integration

Ones the end user pays through website using Stripe payment platform, it should create a new contact within salesforce or it should update old contact with a new record[for old cutsomers] and finally send the Invoice to end users.
Can somebody help with details as well as coding?

i tried below URL's:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/04/recurring-billing-with-the-stripe-sdk-for-salesforce.html

https://github.com/cirruspath/stripeforce

still i getting error:

> [ { "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR", "message": "StripeException: Script-thrown exception\n\nClass.StripeCustomer: line 203, column 1\nClass.StripeCustomer: line 110, column 1\nClass.StripeCustomer.create: line 82, column 1\nClass.CustomRestService.createCustomer: line 9, column 1" } ]

Comment: Well, for this specific error you're going to need to provide us more details of the code. There's some sort of exception being thrown - what's line 9 of the CustomRestService class doing?

Comment: @Robert Watson based on above mentioned url's i got that error,please check above url CustomRestService class 9th line (https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/04/recurring-billing-with-the-stripe-sdk-for-salesforce.html)

Comment: There are apps already out there that will get you up and running in minutes on this or almost any other gateway. Did not know if you were aware